# How to create a calendar object in Java

Tags: java

I need to turn a Date object into a calendar in Java, and try to access its field value for HOUR_OF_DAY. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`setTime`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) method:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: ... and then `int hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest using the [Joda library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you're doing anything more than the most basic date/time work ?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
int hour = dt.getHourOfDay();
```

I realise it's not quite what you're after, but the Joda date/time library offers the benefits of a *much* nicer and intuitive API, and avoids the non-intuitive gotchas of non-thread-safe date/time formatters It's well worth checking out.

Comment: Yes, and it will still be _the_ date/time library in the near future, as it doesn't look like JSR-310 (https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/) is going to be ready for Java 7.