# How to set a custom minimum and maximum date selection day in "wdullaer materialdatetimepicker"

Tags: android, android-studio, datetimepicker, custom-datetimepicker

I am working on a project where I need to restrict the user from choosing any other dates than I want.

by reading some articles and SO post i tried the following which is supposed to work

```
    com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog dpd = newInstance(
                ActivityClaimOffers.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
    dpd.setMinDate(calendar);
    dpd.setMaxDate(calendar);
```

but I 
could not figure out how to pass custom dates as calendar objects.
as both setMinDate() and setMaxDate() takes Calendar as parameter

Comment: Refer this, may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1711820/5567009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```

and for your code:

```
dpd.setMinDate(new GregorianCalendar(2000, 5, 23));
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey try like this code I have done like this

```
Calendar nowMinimum = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this,
            nowMinimum.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            nowMinimum.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            nowMinimum.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dpd.setMinDate(nowMinimum); //today's date is minimum 

    Calendar thenMaximum = Calendar.getInstance();
    thenMaximum.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);// you can pass your custom date 

    dpd.setMinDate(thenMaximum);
    dpd.setTitle("Select Date");
    dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "date_picker");
```